# Is it possible to run parallel tests in separate tabs rather than separate instances/windows of Chrome in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm using the following .conf:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName : 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 6,
    singleWindow: true
}
```

I would like to except to run parallel tests in separate tabs rather than separate instances.
I'm still seeing multiple individual windows appearing and disappearing during execution. These fight for focus and it's very annoying while doing other work.
So, Is it possible to run parallel tests in separate tabs rather than separate instances of Chrome in protractor?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is possible to test on multiple tabs at the same time as each browser has it's own unique selenium sessionID. This ID allow the webdriver to interact with the browser via the JSON wire protocol. When the user wants to interact with specific part of the browser that is not focused by default, such as an iFrame or a new Tab, the focus need to be manually shifted to that using specific commands such as browser.switchTo() but the command are still being sent to the selenium sessionID itself and then to whichever part of the application is focused.

Hope that was clear.

Answer (score 0):

No, is not possible. You can parallelize the test execution using a selenium grid and an external tool to launch those tests, but it is a different setup that the one that you're using.